# How to create 'dates' column for using statsmodels.tsa.arima_model

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, statsmodels

The pandas DataFrame `df` contains the following info:

```
df
           Date   Param1
0    2011-12-21   55.12
1    2011-12-28   70.12
2    2012-01-04   33.73
3    2012-01-11   53.14
4    2012-01-18   74.16
```

To be able to use ARIMA I convert dates as follows:

```
dates = dates_from_range('2011m1', length=len(df.Param1))
df.index = dates
df = df[['Param1']]

from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

res = ARIMA(df, (1,0,0), freq='M').fit()
```

However, in this case instead of getting correct sequence of dates I get this:

```
      Date  Param1
2011-01-31  55.12
2011-02-29  70.12
2011-03-31  33.73
2011-04-30  53.14
2011-05-31  74.16
```

How to avoid using `dates_from_range` and construct dates manually?

Comment: How do you change the dates with `dates_from_range`, could you show the function? Are you trying to change the structure of the dataframe with this line? `df.index = dates \ df = df[['Param1']]` so that the index is dates and the column is 'Param1'?

Comment: Yeah, what skywalker said.  It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.  You start with one 'Date' column, then get rid of it and create a new one as index but you haven't said why or what you want the new one to be.  Are you looking for the pandas `date_range` function?